# How to export raster from PostGIS in one go?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgis-raster

In the simplified canonical example (which I often see on forums and in the books) of a raster exporting script the OID (returned by *lo_create(0)*, here is *9585208*) has to be known before the penultimate script line (*lo_export 9585208 'C:/temp/raster.png'*):

```
SELECT oid, lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), img) As num_bytes
FROM (
    VALUES (
        lo_create(0),
        (SELECT ST_AsPNG(rast)
        FROM bag_o_rasters
        LIMIT 1)
    )
) As v(oid, img);

lo_export 9585208 'C:/temp/raster.png'

SELECT lo_unlink(9585208);
```

I have a hard time with figuring out how to make PSQL cli utility to run this script in one pass, i.e., how to communicate OID returned by *lo_create(0)* to *lo_export* command. It seems the lo_export is client side command and it is not able to digest any query results... please, help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, there is a PSQL command *\gset* which stores values into the script variables, the documentation says:

> *\gset* sends the current query buffer to the server and stores the query's
>   output into psql variables. The query to be executed must return
>   exactly one row. Each column of the row is stored into a separate
>   variable, named the same as the column.

Here is correspondingly modified script:

```
SELECT lo_create(0) as blob_oid

\gset

SELECT oid, lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), img) As num_bytes
FROM (
    VALUES (
        :blob_oid,
        (SELECT ST_AsPNG(rast)
        FROM bag_o_rasters
        LIMIT 1)
    )
) As v(oid,img);

\lo_export :blob_oid 'C:/temp/raster.png'

SELECT lo_unlink(:blob_oid);
```